# Set up Proxy server on Ubuntu

Tags: proxy

Few years ago I have configured proxy server on freebsd by IT guys.
it's functions

- register computers by MAC address.
- filter web sites, messengers, downloads
- set few computers without internet access
- set some computers with limited internet access.
- set some computers with full internet access /using exception by ip/.
- save and review internet usage of people.

i have manual how to add computer by mac, add ban list website and restrict or exception a computer.
but now it's not working and i can't find it guys to fix it

So I want to try it myself on Ubuntu.
Please again please tell me how to configure proxy server on Ubuntu STEP BY STEP?
It's very important for me. Please help me. Or if you have already documented manual please share with me.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

As I understood, you are trying to run a Proxy for other computers on your Ubuntu machine.
I recommend squid.
This is quite simple:
Look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid and follow the steps described there.